# MS Word OLE - replacing text with an image. First block of code works, second does not

Tags: ms-word, lotus-notes, ole

I am editing some code in lotusscript to create a word document off a template using OLE, and am doing a find and replace to add an image.  This works for the first image, however not the second one.

```
objWord.Selection.Find.Execute "{{image1}}",False, True,,,,, 1,,,,,,,
objWord.Selection.Extend
If (objWord.Selection.Characters.Count > 1) Then
    If (signaturefilename = "") Then
        objWord.Selection.Find.Execute "{{image1}}", False, True,,,,, 1,, " ", 2,,,,        
    Else
        Call objWord.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(tempdir + "\" + imagefilename, False, True,)     
    End If
End If

objWord.Selection.Find.Execute "{{image2}}",False, True,,,,, 1,,,,,,,
objWord.Selection.Extend
If (objWord.Selection.Characters.Count > 1) Then
    If (signaturefilename = "") Then
        objWord.Selection.Find.Execute "{{image2}}", False, True,,,,, 1,, " ", 2,,,,        
    Else
        Call objWord.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(tempdir + "\" + imagefilename, False, True,)     
    End If
End If
```

The first section of code works perfectly, however the second one does not replace the second piece of text with the image, as I had expected.

I had expected the second Find.Execute to find the second block of text, however it ends up replacing all the text in the document.

Is there something obvious I have overlooked?

Thanks,

A

Comment: I don't know the Word classes that well, but it seems to me that as a result of the first operation you've narrowed the selection to the part of the document that (originally) contained "{{image1}}".  So before you do your next Find.Execute, you're going to have to expand the selection so that it reaches to the end of the document.

Comment: Yeah, agreed.  I assumed that the 'objWord.Selection.Find.Execute' would go out and find the next string.  I find the documentation from MS a little light on how this should work... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - worked it out.  It was the:

```
objWord.Selection.Extend
```

that needed to be removed.  Although it was not selecting the whole document on the first instance, on the second it was.  This is now working perfectly.  Thanks Richard for the pointer.

In addition, I used the:

```
objWord.Visible = True
```

to assist with debugging.